# How can I use same table view more than one textfield in Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

Hey everyone I am using a text field for search. When I search something, listing data on searchresultvc. And here If I click any row, showing detail of data another VC. Everything ok for here. Problem begins after here. If I search anything on searchresultvc (there is a another textfield), data listing again. But I can't click any row. I am getting error: 'fatal error: Index out of range'.(How can I do effiecently and with at least code)

My ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!
var cName = [String]()
var kTitle = [String]()
var cId = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Basic ...",
        "content-type": "application/json"
    ]

    let encodedSearchText = searchTextField.text?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!

    if let searchText = encodedSearchText{

        Alamofire.request("..../api/GetSearchResult?searchText=\(searchText)", headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.result.value != nil{
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)

                for i in 0...swiftyJsonVar.count{
                    self.cName.append(String(describing: swiftyJsonVar[i]["..."]))
                    self.kTitle.append(String(describing: swiftyJsonVar[i]["..."]))
                    self.cId.append(swiftyJsonVar[i]["contentId"].intValue)
                }

                let srvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchResultVC") as! SearchResultViewController
                srvc.crName = self.cName
                srvc.krTitle = self.kTitle
                srvc.ctId = self.cId
                self.present(srvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And My SearchResult View Controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var crName = [String]()
var krTitle = [String]()
var ctId = [Int]()
var krDetail = String()
var krSource = String()

@IBOutlet weak var dataCount: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    dataCount.text = String(crName.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return crName.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resultCell", for: indexPath) as! SearchResultCellTableViewCell

    cell.kr.text = krTitle[indexPath.row]
    cell.cr.text = crName[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Basic ...",
        "content-type": "application/json"
    ]
    Alamofire.request(".../api/GetResultById?contentId=\(contentId[indexPath.row])", headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.value != nil{
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)

            self.krDetail = String(describing: swiftyJsonVar[0]["..."]).stringByDecodingHTMLEntities
            self.krSource = String(describing: swiftyJsonVar[0]["..."]).stringByDecodingHTMLEntities
            let resultVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultVC") as! ContentResultViewController
            resultVC.course = self.crName[indexPath.row]
            resultVC.content = self.krTitle[indexPath.row]
            resultVC.cDesc = self.krDetail.removeHtmlFromString(inPutString: self.krDetail)
            resultVC.cSource = self.krSource.removeHtmlFromString(inPutString: self.krSource)
            self.present(resultVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}


@IBAction func search(_ sender: Any) {
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Basic ...",
        "content-type": "application/json"
    ]

    let encodedSearchText = searchTextField.text?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!

    if let searchText = encodedSearchText{

        Alamofire.request(".../api/GetSearchResult?searchText=\(searchText)", headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.result.value != nil{
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                self.crName = []
                self.krTitle = []
                for i in 0...swiftyJsonVar.count{
                    self.crName.append(String(describing: swiftyJsonVar[i]["...."]))
                    self.krTitle.append(String(describing: swiftyJsonVar[i]["..."]))
                }

                let srvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchResultVC") as! SearchResultViewController
                srvc.crName = self.crName
                srvc.krTitle = self.krTitle
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                self.present(srvc, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using multiple arrays as data source for a table view is horrible. **Don't do that**. Use a custom struct or class. This avoids most of the home made `out-of-range` errors. And those index-based C-style loops are horrible, too. This is Swift which provides state-of-the-art **fast enumeration** API with or without indexes.

Comment: @vadian Could you help me for non horrible codes :)